# How to Assign a variable after running Run keyword If - else ?

Tags: robotframework

I am trying to assign a variable - `body` ,depending on the status of another variable `phonenumber_id`. If the `phonenumber_id` is `NULL`, `body` gets assigned False.
But it doesnt seem to be working. It works only if he `phonenumber_id` is not `NULL`.

```
${body}=    Run keyword if  '${phonenumber_id}'!='NULL'     Set variable    TRUE
...         Else            Set Variable    FALSE
```

Not sure what i am doing wrong.

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Do you get an error, or is it always setting it to the same value no matter what `${phonenumber_id}` is? Also, are you wanting to check against the _string_ `"NULL"`, or against the python value `None`?

Comment: When the first condition was true, it was assigning ${body} with this   `Set variable    TRUE ...         Else            Set Variable    FALSE  `

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The keyword `Set Variable If` will set a variable based on a given condition

```
${body}=    Set Variable If    '${phonenumer_id} != 'NULL'
...    ${True}    ${False}
```

Comment: But if edit your answer, I remove downvote with joy.

Answer (score 1):

You got it almost right - just mistyped the ELSE  - it must be in capital letters, to be considered a part of the `Run Keyword If`. So in your particular case, it should've been:

```
${body}=    Run keyword if  '${phonenumber_id}'!='NULL'     Set variable    TRUE
...         ELSE            Set Variable    FALSE
```

For the simple case of just setting a new constant value though, @ILostMySpoon [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29424814/3446126) is good enough - and more "readable".

---

In general, for someone stumbling on this post, the `Run Keyword If` combined with `ELSE    Set Variable` is a very powerful construct to set/change a variable - based on the fact that it not only runs a keyword(s) conditionally, but also propagates its return values back to the stack.

Consider this example:

```
${var}=    Run Keyword If    ${bool condition}   Do Some Action Returning A Value    
           ...    ELSE    Set Variable    ${var}
```

In it `{var}` will be set to the return value of `Do Some Action Returning A Value` only if `${bool condition}` evaluates to true, and will keep its old value otherwise.

Another artifical but less abstract example:

```
    ${value}=    Run Keyword If    ${should be int}     Convert To Integer   ${value}
                 ...    ELSE IF    ${should be float}   Convert To Number    ${value}
                 ...    ELSE    Set Variable    ${value}
```